# How to run run a post url?

Tags: asp-classic

What i am trying to do is basically run a script and post data to a page but the page is not on the server. So i dont want to run a redirect, just run a webpage in the back when the user clicks on a button?

I have tried...

```
    set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
Dim var1

var1 = Request("username")

on error resume next
httpRequest.Open "POST", "http://www.example.com", True
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpRequest.send var1
set httpRequest = nothing
```

But this doesnt seem to work. So i want to built the url http://www.example.com?username and run it?

Comment: Do you need the response from the remote server at all? Also is this a script that will be run at the server end, i.e. not in a client browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to include a reference to the jQuery script libraries and use
.ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

a call is simply:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
 </head>
<body>
bip
<div id="result"> results to get replaced here</div>
<div id="msg" style="color:Red">any errors will show here</div>
<input type="button" value="click me" id="loadButton" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        //ensure jQuery is loaded before calling script
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('ready');
        $('#loadButton').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'yoursite/yourpage',
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('doh an error occured. look at the error div above : )');
                    $('#msg').html(xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError); ;
                },
                data: "{'someparam':'someparamvalue','someparam2':'someparamvalue2'}",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    alert('Load was performed.');

                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm sorry i dont know ajax how do i implement this?

Comment: erm how do i set the data to be the var1 i have in my example?

Comment: I cant put values into someparam':'someparamvalue','someparam2':'someparamvalue2 ....The values have to be input by the user which are then posted to the url

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely this line:

```
httpRequest.Open "POST", "http://www.example.com", True
```

Your "True" there is saying run in asynchronous mode, i.e. don't wait for the response before carrying on.  You are then destroying the object immediately so the request is never going to get very far.  Change that "True" to a "False" and you should see the result hit the other server.

---

Edit 1:

Also noticed you are not formatting the POST data correctly, it should take the traditional url formatted `foo=bar`, so the send line needs to be modified like so:

```
httpRequest.send "name=" & var1
```

Sorry I didn't spot this first time!

---

Edit 2:

Here is an example of a working GET transaction with WinHttpRequest:

```
Function GetHTTP(strURL)

    Set objWinHttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    objWinHttp.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objWinHttp.Send

    GetHTTP = objWinHttp.ResponseText

    Set objWinHttp = Nothing

End Function
```

If you do really just need a GET transaction, you can use the following with this function:

```
strResponse = GetHTTP("http://www.example.com/?name=" & Request("username"))
```

And as you don't need the response, just ignore `strResponse` from there on in.

Reference:

[NeilStuff.com - Open Method](http://www.neilstuff.com/winhttp/#Open_Method)

Comment: It still does not work. I dont really need a response from the other server. All i want to be able to do is the user enter some detail on a form, press submit and this gets posted to the example url...so www.example.com?name=enteredDetail